# Unmarshalling a date from an XML file to XMLGregorianCalendar using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I am currently facing a problem while trying to unmarshal a date from an xml file.

**Input XML snippet :**

```
<request>
    <head>
        <title>Load data</title>
        <startDate>20130806</startDate>
        <startTime>20130807-055137</startTime>
    </head>
  <request>
```

The startDate and startTime elements are defined as xs:date and xs:dateTime respectively in the schema file.

After unmarshalling the xml file using JAXB, I get the value in the startDate tag in my java class as follows :

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xcal = request.getHead().getStartDate();
Date date =  xcal.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
System.out.println(date);
```

**Output :** 
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 20130806

I debugged my code and realized that the value 20130806 is held in the year variable of XMLGregorianCalendar. I am not exactly sure why this happens but a possible reason could be that XMLGregorianCalendar needs the date to be in a sepcific format. How do I unmarshal the startDate tag so that I get the date value correctly without needing to write some Adapter and without needing to know the input date format before hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML document does not have the `xs:date` and `xs:dateTime` information in the appropriate format.  If should be the following:

```xml
<request>
    <head>
        <title>Load data</title>
        <startDate>2013-08-06</startDate>
        <startTime>2013-08-07T05:51:37</startTime>
    </head>
  <request>
```

If you want to use an alternate format then you will need to leverage an `XmlAdapter`.